# transmission thump and late shifting

Tags: transmission, lincoln, ls

My 2003 Lincoln LS transmission was thumping going into 3rd gear. Eventually got worse and got codes for transmission. Mechanic replaced the solenoid pack. Now it's still thumping, but not as hard, and in 2nd gear, and not shifting into overdrive at all. Otherwise, engine runs fine. Could it be the wrong solenoid pack, or something else entirely?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!